# ReactPlayer from react-player not working on IOS devices

Tags: reactjs, web, video, frontend, react-player

I'm trying to add a video for a website, the video is working on most devices but on iPhone devices it's not playing, I used react-player as a player for my video.
Here is my code:

```
  <ReactPlayer
  url={companyVideo}
  loop={true}
  muted={true}
  width="100%"
  height="100%"
  playsInline={true}
  playing={true}
/>
```

I tried to add playesinline property hoping it will fix it, but I don't why it didn't work